# If I don't give Zulf the journal, what happens?

Tags: bastion

I'm replaying Bastion. If I never show Zulf the journal, does he still do the same thing as if you *do* give it to him?  (Spoliers below explaining what happens)

> When Zulf reads the journal, he betrays the Bastion to the Ura

Comment: What is the point of this question? What problem are you trying to solve? This is very easy to test and doesn't really have any effect on anything substantial.

Comment: I'm really not sure what you're trying to ask. Could you clarify what you mean by "do what he does"? Specifically which actions are you wondering about?

Comment: @murgatroid99 I don't think it's that easy - you'd have to play at least a couple of hours to check.

Comment: OK, that's true. Before the edit, I made that comment because it seemed like he was asking about something simpler and more pointless.

Comment: Rolling this back because 'still' would depend on what you did first.  And because this one gives a little more warning about the spoilers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Yes, Zulf still betrays the Bastion.

The narration assumes you did show Zulf the journal:

> *When Zulf read that journal*

Comment: No change then?